# Use Google Sheets Script to send email if cell value is null, then update cell value. If already populated, skip row

Tags: email, google-sheets

I am using google sheets script to send an email if not already sent.

```
colA:           colN: 
abc@gmail.com   Yes 
def@gmail.com   
ghi@gmail.com   Yes
```

I want my script to check the value of colB. If null, send the email then change the value to Yes. If not null, skip and proceed to next line. Here is what I have so far.

```
  function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 23; 
  var numRows = 2; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 13)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    // If Column N is null
    if (data[i][13] === ""){
       var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column of selected data
       var message = "....." ; // Assemble the body text
       var subject = ".....";
       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
       data[i][13] = "Yes";
    }
  }
dataRange.setValues(data);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks! That certainly helped. I'm now updating the desired record, but it seems I'm removing all the other records from my source sheet. Am I overwriting more records than just the two I hoped to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your range has 13 columns, meaning that in JavaScript, the second array index runs 0...12. You are referring to 13, which is out of bounds.

2) As written, `dataRange.setValues(data);` writes over the entire dataRange. If the range contains formulas, they will be replaced by static values, which is undesirable. Otherwise, the content should stay the same as it was, except for the entries  of `data` array that you changed. Still, if only a few values in a sheet change, it's better to update them individually, as shown below.

Instead of

```
data[i][12] = "Yes";
```

you can call

```
dataRange.offset(i, 12, 1, 1).setValue("Yes");
```

Comment: Thanks @sandwich! That's exactly what I was hoping to do, but didn't know how.